# How can I align inline paragraph elements better (without table)

Tags: html, css

I am very new to web design and I would like help aligning `p` elements on a web page, just like <kbd>Tab</kbd> aligns things in a word processor.  I have the following code:

```css
.tiny-ps {
  display: block;
}

.big-ps {
  display: none;
}

div.summary-container {
  border: 2px ridge;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

p {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
}

p.highlight {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

p.highlight:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #800000;
}

p.highlight:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #800020;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  div.summary-container {
    margin: 10px 0px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  p.normal {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 2%;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
  p.highlight {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
  .billName {
    display: block;
  }
  .Norm9 {
    font-size: 8pt;
  }
  .tiny-ps {
    display: none;
  }
  .big-ps {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="summary-container">
    <p class="highlight">Address&nbsp;Correction: 3</p>
    <p class="highlight"><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Cour NOT Sent-Shipping: 5</span><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders NOT Sent to Shipping: 5</span></p>
    <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Pickup Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Pickups Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
    <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Liner Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Liners Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
    <p class="normal">Orders Shipped Today: 0</p>
    <p class="normal">Order&nbsp;Received: 14</p>
    <p class="normal">Payment&nbsp;Declined: 6</p>
    <p class="normal">Payment&nbsp;Authorized: 3</p>
    <p class="normal">Mgt&nbsp;Hold: 6</p>
    <p class="normal">Order&nbsp;Sent&nbsp;to&nbsp;Shipping: 3</p>
    <p class="normal">Pending&nbsp;Mgt&nbsp;Approval&nbsp;for&nbsp;PMT: 4</p>
    <p class="normal">HELP&nbsp;ME: 1</p>
    <p class="normal"><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders Sent to Shipping: 2</span><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Courier Sent to Shipping: 2</span></p>
  </div>
```

What I cannot seem to figure out is how to get the text in the paragraphs to line up with the text in the other paragraphs and how to get the numbers to line up with each other. I want to do this *without* having to use a `table`. I can change the markup a little and add class names, but I do not want to use a table. It would look something like this:
[image: how i want it]

Can anybody help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: is that markup mandatory or you can change it?

Comment: I think it's easier to achieve with grid layout

Comment: You would need to use ```table```, ```flexbox``` or other, at least I believe so.

Comment: You'll have to change the markup, the number and the text should be in separate elements  if you want them to line up like that

Comment: This is tabular data, so why not use a table?

Comment: @prettyInPink Flexbox would be the wrong tool as it cant control both height and width at the same time. If you need a table like layout go with css-grid. However this is tabular data and as such also would be suiteable for a table in the first place.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderanlovestrees I can change the markup a little bit but the general idea is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css  'display:inline-block' or 'display:inline-grid' and mention width.

```css
.tiny-ps {
  display: block;
}

.big-ps {
  display: none;
}

div.summary-container {
  border: 2px ridge;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

p {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
}

p.highlight {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

p.highlight:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #800000;
}

p.highlight:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #800020;
}

p.normal {
    display: inline-grid;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="summary-container">
    <p class="highlight">Address&nbsp;Correction: 3</p>
    <p class="highlight"><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Cour NOT Sent-Shipping: 5</span><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders NOT Sent to Shipping: 5</span></p>
    <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Pickup Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Pickups Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
    <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Liner Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Liners Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
    <p class="normal">Orders Shipped Today: 0</p>
    <p class="normal">Order&nbsp;Received: 14</p>
    <p class="normal">Payment&nbsp;Declined: 6</p>
    <p class="normal">Payment&nbsp;Authorized: 3</p>
    <p class="normal">Mgt&nbsp;Hold: 6</p>
    <p class="normal">Order&nbsp;Sent&nbsp;to&nbsp;Shipping: 3</p>
    <p class="normal">Pending&nbsp;Mgt&nbsp;Approval&nbsp;for&nbsp;PMT: 4</p>
    <p class="normal">HELP&nbsp;ME: 1</p>
    <p class="normal"><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders Sent to Shipping: 2</span><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Courier Sent to Shipping: 2</span></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
            .tiny-ps {
             display: block;
            }

            .big-ps {
              display: none;
            }

            div.summary-container {
              border: 2px ridge;
              width: 100%;
              font-weight: normal;
              background-color: #eaeaea;
            }

            p {
              font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
            }

            p.highlight {
              display: block;
              color: #ffffff;
              font-weight: bold;
              text-align: center;
            }

            p.highlight:nth-of-type(odd) {
              background-color: #800000;
            }

            p.highlight:nth-of-type(even) {
              background-color: #800020;
            }

            @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
              div.summary-container {
                margin: 10px 0px;
              }
              p {
                font-size: 12pt;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                margin-top: 5px;
              }
              p.normal {
                display: inline;
                margin-right: 2%;
                font-size: 12pt;
              }
              p.highlight {
                display: block;
                margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
                font-size: 12pt;
              }
              .billName {
                display: block;
              }
              .Norm9 {
                font-size: 8pt;
              }
              .tiny-ps {
                display: none;
              }
              .big-ps {
                display: inline-block;
              }
            }
            #num{
                width: 5%;
                text-align:left;
                padding-block:initial;
            }
            #std{
                text-align:left;
            }
            .cent{
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
```

```html
<div class="summary-container">
            <p class="highlight">Address&nbsp;Correction: 3</p>
            <p class="highlight"><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Cour NOT Sent-Shipping: 5</span><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders NOT Sent to Shipping: 5</span></p>
            <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Pickup Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Pickups Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
            <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Liner Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Liners Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
            <table class="cent">
                <tr>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Orders Shipped Today:</td><td id="num">0</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Order&nbsp;Received: </td><td id="num">14</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Payment&nbsp;Declined: </td><td id="num">6</p></td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Payment&nbsp;Authorized: </td><td id="num">3</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Mgt&nbsp;Hold: </td><td id="num">6</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Order&nbsp;Sent&nbsp;to&nbsp;Shipping: </td><td id="num">3</p></td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Pending&nbsp;Mgt&nbsp;Approval&nbsp;for&nbsp;PMT: </td><td id="num">4</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">HELP&nbsp;ME: </td><td id="num">1</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal"><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders Sent to Shipping: </td><td id="num">2</span><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Courier Sent to Shipping: 2</span></p></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

```css
.tiny-ps {
        display: block;
      }
      
      .big-ps {
        display: none;
      }
      
      div.summary-container {
        border: 2px ridge;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: normal;
        background-color: #eaeaea;
      }
      
      p {
        font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
      }
      
      p.highlight {
        display: block;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      p.highlight:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: #800000;
      }
      
      p.highlight:nth-of-type(even) {
        background-color: #800020;
      }
      
      @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
        div.summary-container {
          margin: 10px 0px;
        }
        p {
          font-size: 12pt;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
          margin-top: 5px;
        }
        p.normal {
          border: 1px unset;
          padding:7px;
          text-align:right;
          font-size: 12pt;
          margin-left: 20px;
          margin-right: auto;
        }
        p.highlight {
          display: block;
          margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
          font-size: 12pt;
        }
        .billName {
          display: block;
        }
        .Norm9 {
          font-size: 8pt;
        }
        .tiny-ps {
          display: none;
        }
        .big-ps {
          display: inline-block;
        }
        .grid-container{
          grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
          
          display:grid;
          padding:10px;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="summary-container">
      <p class="highlight">Address&nbsp;Correction: 3</p>
      <p class="highlight"><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Cour NOT Sent-Shipping: 5</span><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders NOT Sent to Shipping: 5</span></p>
      <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Pickup Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Pickups Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
      <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Liner Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Liners Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
      <div class="grid-container">
        <p class="normal">Orders Shipped Today:</p><p class="normal">0</p>
        <p class="normal">Order&nbsp;Received:<p class="normal">14</p>
        <p class="normal">Payment&nbsp;Declined:<p class="normal">6</p>
        <p class="normal">Payment&nbsp;Authorized:<p class="normal">3</p>
        <p class="normal">Mgt&nbsp;Hold:<p class="normal">6</p>
        <p class="normal">Order&nbsp;Sent&nbsp;to&nbsp;Shipping:<p class="normal">3</p>
        <p class="normal">Pending&nbsp;Mgt&nbsp;Approval&nbsp;for&nbsp;PMT:<p class="normal">4</p>
        <p class="normal">HELP&nbsp;ME:<p class="normal">1</p>
        <p class="normal"><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders Sent to Shipping:</p><p class="normal">2</p></span><p class="normal"><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Courier Sent to Shipping:2</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This time Without using table.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS's `text-indent` property.

```
p {
  text-indent: 45px
}
```

Adjust the pixel value to whatever fits. You can also use a percentage value for responsive sites.

Comment: could you provide an example of usage with the number aligned?

Comment: This is not going to do it. Did you test this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Expedited/Courier Orders Sent to Shipping
```

you can also put in table

```css
.tiny-ps {
  display: block;
}

.big-ps {
  display: none;
}

div.summary-container {
  border: 2px ridge;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

p {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
}
p.highlight {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

p.highlight:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #800000;
}

p.highlight:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #800020;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  div.summary-container {
    margin: 10px 0px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  p.normal {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 2%;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
  p.highlight {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
  .billName {
    display: block;
  }
  .Norm9 {
    font-size: 8pt;
  }
  .tiny-ps {
    display: none;
  }
  .big-ps {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="summary-container">
    <p class="highlight">Address&nbsp;Correction: 3</p>
    <p class="highlight"><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Cour NOT Sent-Shipping: 5</span><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders NOT Sent to Shipping: 5</span></p>
    <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Pickup Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Pickups Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
    <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Liner Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Liners Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
    <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Orders Shipped Today:</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>Order&nbsp;Received:</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>Payment&nbsp;Declined:</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Payment&nbsp;Authorized:</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Mgt&nbsp;Hold:</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Order&nbsp;Sent&nbsp;to&nbsp;Shipping:</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pending&nbsp;Mgt&nbsp;Approval&nbsp;for&nbsp;PMT:</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>HELP&nbsp;ME: 1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Payment&nbsp;Declined:</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    
    <p class="normal"><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders Sent to Shipping: 2</span><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Courier Sent to Shipping: 2</span></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I can't use a table because I'm using xsl to generate the markup and it would be beyond too hard to try to change it for a tabular design.

Answer (score 1):

```css
            .tiny-ps {
             display: block;
            }

            .big-ps {
              display: none;
            }

            div.summary-container {
              border: 2px ridge;
              width: 100%;
              font-weight: normal;
              background-color: #eaeaea;
            }

            p {
              font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
            }

            p.highlight {
              display: block;
              color: #ffffff;
              font-weight: bold;
              text-align: center;
            }

            p.highlight:nth-of-type(odd) {
              background-color: #800000;
            }

            p.highlight:nth-of-type(even) {
              background-color: #800020;
            }

            @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
              div.summary-container {
                margin: 10px 0px;
              }
              p {
                font-size: 12pt;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                margin-top: 5px;
              }
              p.normal {
                display: inline;
                margin-right: 2%;
                font-size: 12pt;
              }
              p.highlight {
                display: block;
                margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
                font-size: 12pt;
              }
              .billName {
                display: block;
              }
              .Norm9 {
                font-size: 8pt;
              }
              .tiny-ps {
                display: none;
              }
              .big-ps {
                display: inline-block;
              }
            }
            #num{
                width: 5%;
                text-align:left;
                padding-block:initial;
            }
            #std{
                text-align:left;
            }
            .cent{
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
```

```html
<div class="summary-container">
            <p class="highlight">Address&nbsp;Correction: 3</p>
            <p class="highlight"><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Cour NOT Sent-Shipping: 5</span><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders NOT Sent to Shipping: 5</span></p>
            <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Pickup Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Pickups Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
            <p class="highlight"><span class="big-ps">Liner Orders Not Sent to Shipping: 1</span><span class="tiny-ps">Liners Not Sent-Shipping: 1</span></p>
            <table class="cent">
                <tr>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Orders Shipped Today:</td><td id="num">0</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Order&nbsp;Received: </td><td id="num">14</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Payment&nbsp;Declined: </td><td id="num">6</p></td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Payment&nbsp;Authorized: </td><td id="num">3</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Mgt&nbsp;Hold: </td><td id="num">6</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Order&nbsp;Sent&nbsp;to&nbsp;Shipping: </td><td id="num">3</p></td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">Pending&nbsp;Mgt&nbsp;Approval&nbsp;for&nbsp;PMT: </td><td id="num">4</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal">HELP&nbsp;ME: </td><td id="num">1</p></td>
                <td id="std"><p class="normal"><span class="big-ps">Expedited/Courier Orders Sent to Shipping: </td><td id="num">2</span><span class="tiny-ps">Exped/Courier Sent to Shipping: 2</span></p></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please tell me this is usefull for you

Comment: It looks kinda rough. I edited my question to ask for a solution without a table